# Spring multiuser application overrides session

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, concurrency, spring-security

I'm developing my web app with Spring MVC 2.5.6 and I need some help for multiple user sessions in it. The header of my app shows the logged user.

In my computer, I open two browsers (no tabs):

- In the first one, I log in my app with *user1* and get into. In the header, *user1* appears.
- In the second, I log in with *user2* and go on. In the header, *user2* appears.

Then, I switch to the first browser, submit an operation to the controller and when the app is showed again, in the header *user2* appears, and it's wrong because I logged in with *user1*.

So, my questions are:

- `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()` may not be the right way to get the logged user with many users, because it's singleton (isn't it?). How could I do this?
- This wrong situation is also happening with session object, so *user1* data stored in the session object (managed with `request.getSession().setAttribute(...)` and `request.getSession.getAttribute(...)`) is override with *user2* data.
- In this StackOverflow question, [Handling Session ID with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934267/handling-session-id-with-spring), it's suggested that session ID would be managed to separate data. Should I manage manually each user data with session ID internally in my application? How could I get the session ID?

In general terms, my problem is with dealing with multiple users/sessions.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Comment: What's exactly the problem? When you use two browsers, you have two sessions with different users logged in, that's how it's intended to work.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't know the session is shared among the same browser instances. But it seems to be the normal behaviour. Thanks axtavt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my computer, I open two browsers (no tabs):
>
> - In the first one, I log in my app with user1 and get into. In the header, user1 appears.
> - In the second, I log in with user2 and go on. In the header, user2 appears.
>
> Then, I switch to the first browser, submit an operation to the controller and when the app is showed again, in the header user2 appears, and it's wrong because I logged in with user1.

With session as normally implemented, this is normal behavior if the client is running two windows or tabs of the same browser on the same machine, as they share the session.

If you open the app in IE and Firefox, they will not share a session, and things will work properly.

I don't believe there's a way to get the browser to stop sharing session among windows, so if you need them to act independently, you'll need to essentially create your own session mechanism, likely by using hidden fields or some such hack rather than the cookies or url-rewriting the normal mechanism uses.

It would be better to just accept the situation.  Let the user know when they open the second window and connect to your app that they are already logged in, and don't allow another login.

Comment: +1 (but only if the OP is really using the same browser twice ^^)

Comment: @Axel - indeed - if this is happening other than that situation, there's a real issue, and I'd want to see code.

Comment: Well, thank you all. It's better for me, so that's not an incidence or wrong behaviour in my app. Thanks again